# How to know from which DOM click event is triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have few `Card` component from material UI, each of them contain an `EDIT` button and there is a handler available for it, they are being added dynamically using `Map` traversing (In example, i have just hard coded two of them).

Now, i am trying to make the card editable in button click but not able to find out how to get to know from which Card, event is triggered and then make "Typography" of that editable to 'TextField'.

```
 <CardContent>
    <Typography>ID: '1'</Typography>
    <Typography
      className={classes.title}
      color="textSecondary"
      gutterBottom
    >
      Word of the Day
    </Typography>
    <Typography>Name: 'RAAM'</Typography>
    <Typography>Blood group: 'AB+'</Typography>
    <Typography>"Patient Ram is having bloodgroup AB+"</Typography>
  </CardContent>
  <CardActions>
    <Button size="small" onClick={click}>
      Edit
    </Button>
  </CardActions>
  <CardContent>
```

Here is my codeSandbox example
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wesss?file=/demo.js)

Comment: can you include also in the post the `click` method?

Comment: @vsync Its pretty basic so did not post here, though its available in codesandbox link.

Comment: You must have some identifier for each card.. you need to pass it to `click` method. you should then update the state accordingly and then react to the state change to update the DOM, make that specific card editable.

Comment: Do you know how to work with react state? `useState` for example?

Comment: How come your card has 2 cards inside of it..? this is not proper

Comment: @Lara, updated my answer. You can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    minWidth: 275
  },
  bullet: {
    display: "inline-block",
    margin: "0 2px",
    transform: "scale(0.8)"
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12
  }
});

export default function OutlinedCard() {
  const refs = useRef([]);
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  const click = (event) => {
    const { currentTarget: { id = "" } = {} } = event;
    const clickedCard = refs.current[id]; // This is the card whose button got clicked
    console.log(clickedCard);
  };

  const createRefs = (id, node) => (refs.current[id] = node);

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
      <CardContent ref={(node) => {createRefs('card_1', node)}}>
        <Typography>ID: '1'</Typography>
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="textSecondary"
          gutterBottom
        >
          Word of the Day
        </Typography>
        <Typography>Name: 'RAAM'</Typography>
        <Typography>Blood group: 'AB+'</Typography>
        <Typography>"Patient Ram is having bloodgroup AB+"</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" id="card_1" onClick={click}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
      <CardContent ref={(node) => {createRefs('card_2', node)}}>
        <Typography>ID: '2'</Typography>
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="textSecondary"
          gutterBottom
        >
          Word of the Day
        </Typography>
        <Typography>Name: 'RAAM'</Typography>
        <Typography>Blood group: 'AB+'</Typography>
        <Typography>"Patient Ram is having bloodgroup AB+"</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" id="card_2" onClick={click}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: She doesn't have a *class* in her code... she uses *functional* React, hence - this doesn't help her

Comment: @vsync okay, updated code as per her. ID's are hardcoded but it should be dynamic incase she uses array to render cards.

Answer (score 3):

The usual solution is to have the card pass back some identifying information or an object that you've passed it, since there's very little you can do with the React element.

If you want the DOM element, it's the `currentTarget` property of the event object that your `click` function receives.

Here's a simple example showing both with stand-ins for `Card` and its parent, in this case the `Card` component returns the `id` you pass it as a second argument to the click function:

```js
"use strict";

const cards = Array.from(Array(5), (_, index) => ({
    id: index + 1,
    value: `Card ${index + 1}`
}));

function Parent() {
    const click = (evt, id) => {
        console.log(`evt.currentTarget.tagName = ${evt.currentTarget.tagName}, id = ${id}`);
    };
    return cards.map(({id, value}) =>
        <Card
          key={id}
          value={value}
          onClick={evt => click(evt, id)}
        />
    );
}

function Card({value, onClick}) {
    return <div onClick={onClick}>{value}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like this approach better: `onClick={click(id)}` and `const click = id => e => ...`

Comment: @vsync - To each their own. :-) They do the same thing in the end.